# Updating Yammer relationships via API

Tags: api, yammer

Has anyone successfully used the Yammer REST API to POST updates to the relationships API?

I'm trying to use the API to update someone's Manager/Superior/Boss

The documentation is not very clear and seems to always return a 201 response even though the updates do not appear to work.

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/relationshipsjson-1

The documentation refers to [ subordinate | superior | colleague ]=email_address

but the response from this API call uses different adjectives and returns [ "boss", "report", "colleague" ]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the documentation here has a bug. I'll see if I can suggest edits to that.

The API can be called like the following (where 123456 is the user id of the boss):

usernames[boss][]=123456

I presume that you could even do something like:

usernames[boss][]=123456&usernames[colleague][]=123457&usernames[report][]=123458&usernames[report][]=123459